# A series that converges absolutely and a bounded series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I got this exercise in my latest calculus homework assignment. I struggled with it 
but came up with nothing.

The question is this:

assume that  -  $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:a_n$  converges absolutely. Also, assume that $\left(b_n\right)$ is a bounded series. Show that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:a_nb_n$ converges absolutely.

So basicly, I need to show that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:|a_nb_n|$ converges. Because $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:a_n$ converges absolutely I can write $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:|a_n|b_n$. But how to I proceed from here?

A few problems I have understanding the question:

1. Should I assume that $b_n$ is an infinite series?
2. If $b_n$ is **bounded**, does that mean its bounded from above **and** below? because I might need to split this into different cases.
3. How can I use the bounded definition to show this?

Any help will be great!!  Thanks and have a great week.

Comment: Do you mean that $(b_n)$ is a bounded **sequence**?

Comment: hint: use the Cauchy criterion

Answer (score 2):

The usual definition of **boundedness** of a sequence $(b_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is that there exists $M\geq 0$ such that $\left|b_n\right|\leq M$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Note that this is equivalent to stating that $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded above and below.

*Hint*: Use the definition of boundedness (including $M$) explicitly to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left|a_nb_n\right|$ converges.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your hint helped me solve this one...Thanks! :)

Comment: Great, @elmekRaeL!

Answer (score 2):

Since the sequence $(b_n)$ is bounded there exists $M>0$ such that for all $n\in\mathbf{N}$, $|b_n|<M$. So we have 
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }|a_nb_n|\leq M\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }|a_n|<\infty.$$
Then $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }|a_nb_n|$ is convergent.

Comment: Thats the the way I solved it. Thanks!!